# How App class is autmatically loaded in cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

how can any class in cakephp have access to the App class without including it's class definition?

And also what is the use of build.xml file in the root folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `App` class is being included in the CakePHP [**core bootstrap**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.6.2/lib/Cake/bootstrap.php#L139), which in turn is included in your apps [**`/webroot/index.php`**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.6.2/app/webroot/index.php#L96-L107).

The `build.xml` file, well, just take a look at [**its contents**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.6.2/build.xml#L4-L16):

> Build.xml file for CakePHP
>
> Uses phing to create releases, and pear packages.
>   Based off of build.xml in doctrine.
>
> Requires the cakephp/d51PearPkg2 to be installed:
>
> pear channel-discover pear.domain51.com
>   pear install cakephp/Phing_d51PearPkg2Task
>
> Use the `release` task to update VERSION.txt, and create a new tag.
>   Use the `build` task to create a pear package based on the current working copy.
>   Use the `clean` task to clean up packaging artifacts.

Comment: does it mean that "/webroot/index.php" is executed before each url request?

Comment: @DesirePRG Yes, it's the entry point of your application. Again a look at [**the files contents**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.6.2/app/webroot/index.php#L3-L5) might give you a hint: `Index ... The Front Controller for handling every request`.